# Applications of random walks

Tags: probability, reference-request, soft-question

I am searching for a clear and interesting exposition of an application of random walks to some physics topics accessible to advanced high school students.

Comment: Did you try [the obvious](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#Applications)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article on Gambler's Ruin.

http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/FE-Notes/4700-07-Notes-GR.pdf

If the students have some probability background, you could probably make (most of) the ideas in this article make sense to them.